# Using topojson for time-lapse maps

Tags: maps, versioning, geojson, topojson

I would like to make a map that animates through the political borders of the U.S. over time. Others have already done wonderful work compiling [Shapefiles and GeoJSON files](http://poezn.github.io/us-history-maps/) of every version of the United States from its inception. It's a version-control map of the U.S., if you will.

This seems like an absolutely perfect job for topoJSON, since only parts of the polygons change with each iteration. Borders get moved, states get divided or joined, etc. But I'm stumbling over how exactly to reduce the massive redundancy in these files while preserving the information about which year each belongs to.

I'd like to be able to load one topoJSON file and then manipulate which arcs are drawn based on the given year being viewed at that time. I can certainly combine these files and convert to topoJSON no problem, and write the Javascript to control the animate when the time comes, but not sure how to preserve the time element.

Comment: This is a great question. Did you try GIS Exchange? My guess is you are best off creating one Topojson file for all your main, static features. Then use a separate Topojson or vector tile file as the dynamic element.